# Stop a formula running once data is in place

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I'm looking for some help with Excel and have created the problem in a Google sheet to highlight.

I'm trying to get a column (C) to auto-fill a value when data is entered in a second column (D). The auto-filled data is pulled from cell A1.

The data in cell A1 will change each week and I don't want the rows with auto-filled data to update with the new value. Once entered, the data should be set.

For example, a cell in C gets autofilled with a '1' when some text is entered in column D. Next week a '2' is entered in A1. The cell in C should not change from a '1' to a '2'.

You can see the formula I currently have in the sheet below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W6xRqpEAiVxKye0whMJd7ODbwLQaOtDLQdEB59j4brY/edit?usp=sharing can anyone help with stopping the cells updating once a value is present?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to use vba to paste.special values once the date has passed then the cell will stop updating.

Comment: This will require vba/Google script.  Excel does allow the use of circular references, it is not robust enough to rely on.  And google sheets does not even allow it.

Comment: Use the associated "edit" event to call some function to compute the desired value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is possible in Google Sheets:

```
=if(isblank(D3),A$1,C3)
```

in C3 and copied down to suit.

Requires setting Spreadsheet settings... > Calculation > Iterative calculation to `On` (`Max number of iterations` to 1 is enough) and is not good practice.

The C column values will track the A1 value as long as the corresponding (ie same row) D column cells are blank.

Basically the same in Excel.

Comment: this is working as hoped, the number stays fixed once data is in place in Column D. To tidy it up though is there a way to adapt the formula so that when nothing is entered in column D, Column C remains blank. If you look at the sheet now, Column C is filled with numbers even though no data is present in Column D. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've solved this issue using conditional formatting. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a formula is a mistake. If you don't want the existing week number to be updated, then you need to assign the week number as a value. You could do this manually, but the easiest way is to use a macro (VBA). Insert a shape (button) on that sheet, add meaningful text, assign a macro (like the one below). Then when you are ready to update week numbers, just click the button.

```
Sub updateweekid()
Dim weekid As Long
Dim lastweekrow As Long, lastclientrow As Long

'get week #
weekid = Cells(1, 1).Value


'week list is column C, row2
'Find the last non-blank cell in column C(3)
lastweekrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

'client list is column d, row2
'Find the last non-blank cell in column D(4)
lastclientrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row


'loop though updating week number
For i = 1 To (lastclientrow - lastweekrow)
Cells(lastweekrow + i, 3).Value = weekid
Next i

End Sub
```